# Writing to a read-only file using XmlWriter in .NET

Tags: .net, xmlwriter, readonly

I would like to write to a read-only file using [`XmlWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx). What is the proper way to do this?

Currently I have:

```
XmlWriterSettings lSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
lSettings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
lSettings.Indent = true;

XmlWriter lWriter = XmlWriter.Create(lPath, lSettings);
lXml.WriteContentTo(lWriter);
lWriter.Close();
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid clearing and re-setting the read-only flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a file is set as read-only, you do need to re-set the flag, no workarounds.

Of course, you could *delete* the file (which still requires you to clear the flag) and write a new one, but then risk that if your write operation doesn't happen (exception somewhere), you lose the contents.

Comment: Deleting the file will still require clearing the read-only flag first.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it  you must remove the read-only flag to write to a file given the fact that this flag is controlled directly by the operating system.

If what you want is avoid the possibility that someone else can write to the file in the time the write flag is enabled you can do a temporary copy of the file (with write permissions), write your XML to that file and finally replace the original file with yours and set the flag to read-only.